# PDOでPHPからMySQLに接続。PHPでDBの内容を変更したいのですがうまくいきません。

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

update.php（コード①）で、データベースの内容表示+変更内容入力フォーム+登録ボタンを表示して、表示された内容を変更するところまではできます。

しかし、登録を押しても画面が切り替わらず変更内容も反映されません。
update_do.php（コード②）に変更内容がPOSTを利用して送信されるような形にしたいのですが、送信できていないようです。
エラー表示は特にないのでどこがおかしいのか教えてください。

初めての質問なので、ほかになにか必要な情報があればお申し付けください。
よろしくお願いします。

引用元:
書籍「よくわかるPHPの教科書」

**update.php**

```
<?php require('dbconnect.php'); ?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<main>
<h2>practice</h2>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" charset="utf-8">

<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['id']) && is_numeric($_REQUEST['id'])) {
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];

    $memos = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM memos WHERE id=?');
    $memos->execute(array($id));
    $memo = $memos->fetch();
}
?>

<from action="update_do.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php print($id); ?>">
    <textarea name="memo" cols="50" rows="10"><?php print($memo['memo']); ?></textarea><br>
    <button type="submit">登録する</button>
</from>
</main>
```

**update_do.php**

```
<?php require('dbconnect.php'); ?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<main>
<h2>practice</h2>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" charset="utf-8">

<?php
$statement = $db->prepare('UPDATE memos SET memo=? WHERE id=?');
$statement->execute(array(!empty($_POST['memo']), (!empty($_POST['id']))));
?>
<p>メモの内容を変更しました。</p>
<p><a href="index.php">戻る</a></p>
</main>
```

Comment: 画面が切り替わらないということは、PDOは関係ない話ですかね？PDOを抜いた形の最小限のコードでも再現しますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。PDOを抜くとPHPからデータベースの内容を変更できないという認識なのですがいかがでしょうか、、。PDOを抜いて（<?php require('dbconnect.php'); ?>をコード上から削除）やってみたところエラー表示が出ます（Notice: Undefined variable: db in C:\xampp\htdocs\input.html\update_do.php on line 15

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\input.html\update_do.php:15 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\input.html\update_do.php on line 15）

Comment: そもそもupdate_do.phpのページに移動していないのですよね？でしたらPDOやなんやらは関係ないと思います。ページ移動ができていて画面が真っ白になるとか画面はできるけどデータが登録されていないということであれば、PDOの問題になると思います。ちなみにupdate_do.phpのページに直接アクセスすればエラーは出るかもしれないですけど見れますよね？

Comment: $memoや$idもPHPを利用してDBから取得するのではなく、何かしら固定の値にするとどうなりますか？

Comment: update_do.phpに直接アクセスすると、エラー表示はないのですが編集内容が表示されず”メモの内容を変更しました”と“戻る”以外表示されない状態です。PHPを利用してDB上から取得しているのは、既存のDB上にある情報を出すためなのでそこはそのままにしたいです。やりたい形としては、すでにDB上にある内容をPHPを利用して表示し、その内容をPHPで変更し(update.php)、変更内容を表示し(update_do.php)、DB上でもその内容が反映される形にしたいのですがどうでしょうか。

Comment: 繰り返しになりますが、画面が切り替わらず、もとの画面から移動できないのであればPDOの問題ではなくてHTMLの問題の可能性が高いです。

Comment: どこが問題かわかりますか？？市販の教材をみながら学習していて教材通りのはずなのですが、、。update.php内の"<button type="submit">登録する</button>"に関して、こちらはsubmitで問題ないでしょうか？

Comment: 市販の教材どおりであれば、教材の引用の情報も載せた方がいいでしょう

Comment: 失礼致しました。質問本文に追加致しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form` ではなくて`from`になっているため、フォームとして送信されないのだと思います。
タグは正しく`form`を利用しましょう
これでページ遷移ができるようになると思います。

Comment: 完全に見落としておりました、、、。無事正常に動作するようになりました！！ありがとうございます。とても助かりました！